# find help without javadoc

Tags: java

I want to access java comment 
/**
*/
of   java source file (ie java.lang.String)of JDK from command line for find help.
I used javap command but I am getting only signature of method I want to read description also.
I also aware with java  documentation but I dont want to use it.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for not doing this the one obvious way they're meant to be done?

Comment: This is the reason people use IDE's so that things are integrated :)

Answer (score 6):

Comments don't make it into the class files.

> I also aware with java dicumentation but I dont want to use it.

That's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not from command line, you can visit a website such as [docjar.com](http://www.docjar.com/), which is an online resource containing the sources to all Java classes.

If you *must* have it accessible on the command line, you could write a program to fetch documentation from a site like docjar and then output it to the command line.